# How do I correctly wire a new light/switch from an outlet?

Tags: wiring, receptacle, led, dimmer-switch, light

I’m installing an LED strip and would like to run a switch from the existing outlet.  I’ve made a diagram that I believe is correct.  Anything I’m missing?[image]

Answer (score 1):

Electrically, this will work and your diagram is correct. You're lacking a bunch of construction concerns though. How are you getting from outlet to switch?, from switch to transformer, where will tx be mounted, what type of wire, etc.

Comment: The power is coming from the panel.  15a.  I would use 14/2 Romex from the outlet to the switch.  The outlet and new switch and new transformer are close to each other.

Comment: If the diagram is correct, my next question would be do I pigtail the white wires at the outlet to switch and switch to transformer?  Is there specific spots on the outlet to run the black wire?

Comment: Your white wire will be connected to the outlet too.  Outlets hav in and out screws for continuing the run but I've always been a fan of pigtailing neutrals and hots and connecting those to the screw terminals of the outlet. You'll just connect the whites together at the switch unless your switch needs a neutral, then you'll pigtail.

Comment: Jack is right , and mentioned the transformer where is this going? In a separate box in a large box with the switch? It matters if you want to be code compliant.

Answer (score 0):

Just want to make sure I have this right...

Power is coming from the outlet black wire to the dimmer switch.  The red wire from the dimmer switch carries the power to the led transformer and on to the led strip.

The white wire from the led transformer is pigtailed to the White from the outlet to carry the current back.

Yes?

Each will be boxed independently.

[image: Wiring]

Comment: What's that extra wire??  (not the ground wire, which has to be hooked up too.)

Comment: This should be edited into you first question or in a comment.